# Access data from javascript file to a html file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm in need of keeping my base url in a separate js file. I've created a js file called `config.js` and inside it

```
export const baseUrl = "https://example.com/";
```

I also have several html files that use the above base url to do some actions. For ex:

```
<ul style="display:grid">
  <li><a href="https://example.com/static/geonode/final/${crop}/data.zip" target="_blank">Agro Climatic Data</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I have many scenarios like this. If I wanted to change my base url I have to change each and every line that contain the url. I want to access the base url i specified in my config.js to use in my html files, so if I had to change it, I only have to do it once. How can I do this?

Comment: There is also a HTML [base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag which does the same. Though it's for every single (relative) path you specify in your document

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    const baseUrl = "https://example.com/";

    var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
        aTags[i].setAttribute("href", baseUrl + aTags[i].getAttribute("href"))
    }
```

```js
   const baseUrl = "https://example.com/";


   var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
   for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
       aTags[i].setAttribute("href", baseUrl + aTags[i].getAttribute("href"))
    }
```

```html
    <ul style="display:grid">
        <li><a href="static/geonode/final/${crop}/data.zip" target="_blank">Agro Climatic Data</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: But the issue is i have several other place that i use this base url other than in hrefs

Comment: OK you can access those objects in your javascript code

Comment: You know with pure javascript you can't access the javascript variable unless in event `onclick or another event`

Comment: @crazydroid if your Objects has events such as `onclick` you can write a global function and set computed url to those object.

Comment: This answer would be better if it had some explanation of the code and how it solves the OP's problem.